# 'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: configuration, command-line, batch-file

I'm running a batch file command on a  server which is using reg query to find out the procesor_architecture of the machine(AMD64 or x86).

And I'm getting this error, does anyone know what could be the issue.
And what all things have to be checked first before running this command on that specific server.

This is the command:

```
reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.
```

I don't know if this helps or not. But the OS is W2k Advances SP 4 on the server.

Comment: Are you sure the that user executing the script has permission to run `reg`, i.e. if they typed `reg` at the command prompt, would it work or would they get an error?

Comment: yes it is not the permission issue.Because I m able to run some other set of servers in the chain with same credentials.

Comment: path issue? is the path environment getting set in the batch somewhere? reg.exe is normally in \Windows\system32

Comment: You may need to install reg.exe to win2k server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301423/en-us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 2000 didn't include `reg.exe` yet. However, you can find the processor architecture in the environment variables:

```
> echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
AMD64
```

Re-reading your question: Heck, that's what you've been trying anyway, so why bother with the convoluted way when you can just grab the value directly?

Comment: That's not true. Windows 2000 had reg.exe,because I ran the same query on windows 2000 not on advanced and it was successfull. But I don't know Advanced SP4

Comment: It didn't exist on my Windows 2000 Professional back when I still had it. It came in a Resource Kit as far as I remember. Anyway, *that's not the point here.* You're fishing something out of the registry *which is available as an environment variable.* There is no *need* to consult the registry here since you already have the value directly.

Comment: I completely agree with you Rossell.But I mistakenly took the wrong path of querying registry instead of using environmental variable.I  didn't think about windows 2000 servers.

Answer (score 11):

I have seen this when a tech used a batch file variable called 'path' in a script. Set the PATH variable back to C:\Windows\System32 and that should fix your reg.exe not found errors.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this error is to add the path C:\Windows\System32\ to the Environment Variables:

1. Right click the My Computer icon then choose properties.
2. Select the Advanced tab and then click Environment Variables.
3. At the system variables panel, choose Path then click the Edit button.
4. Add C:\Windows\System32, the paths are separated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

"reg" does not appear to be in the path in the environment in which you are executing it. Try using the full path to "reg".