# SDK Tools issue tried to update got this issue

Tags: eclipse, sdk

I am facing this problem for about 4 days already uninstall the whole eclipse + sdk re installed every thing. I am now to desperate and angry cant solve this issue read and tried everything available online.The sdk manager loading but it wont open and the 2 errors below shows. Please help really desperate and thanks in advance plus i have tried everything told here before.

```
**[2014-12-12 18:01:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**

**[2014-12-12 18:01:20 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.**
```

Comment: Which SDK? Eclipse has many different SDKs

Comment: possible duplicate of ['reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313512/reg-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

Comment: ruslan already read than one no use of it

Answer (score 0):

Did you just install the android SDK Tools 24.0.1?  After i did i had the same problem.  I found another thread here that suggested uninstalling the update: [Android Studio Error 'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366895/android-studio-error-reg-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

The post from "Sheraz Ahmad Khilji" worked for me.  Once you remove the updated SDK Tools, the whole Tools file will disappear, so make sure you download the tools folder that he posted and copy it over.

Hope this helps you too.

Comment: my issue has been resolved by the way i coppied some folders from my friend who was using android luna as was i. When i copied those folders all the issues got resolved. Basically the problem started after updating it to 24.0.1